# Change class value javascript in event onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

hello I need to do it only in javascript (not in jquery)

How would you do something equivalent in javascript something like this in query?

```
    <body>

    <div class="wysiwyg">text......text...</div>

<div class="btn btn-primary verMas">Ver más</div>

    <script>
     $('.verMas').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
           $('.wysiwyg').css('height','auto');
           $(this).hide();
            $('.layerMiddle').hide();
        });
    </script></body>
```

Comment: Have you tried to create this in javascript yourself, should be very simple if you break it down 1 line/function at the time

Comment: check this http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/ and go line by line and it should be pretty easy

Comment: basic querySelector, addEventListener, and style

Comment: I think they don't understand me, I don't want to use jquery, just javascript

Answer (score 1):

Your example suggests that you need to be able to

1. Select Items from the DOM
2. Add an on-click event listener
3. Modify the display state of elements

Looking at how you might achieve these in native JS then I would suggest the following:

1. [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

This provides some similar functionality to JQuery's selectors - at least for this use case.

2. [`element.addEventListener('click', function)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

This provides equivalent functionality as JQuery's `$('').click(function)`

3. [`element.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

This enables modification of the in-line style of the element so setting the style of `display` to `none` can achieve this

*Putting these all together:*

```js
// use querySelector to get the .verMas element and add on-click event listener
document.querySelector('.verMas').addEventListener('click', e => {

  // prevent default event
  e.preventDefault()

  // use querySelector to get the .wysiwyg element
  // set the style.height parameter to auto
  document.querySelector('.wysiwyg').style.height = 'auto'

  // e.target is the element that this event was fired on 
  // to hide it, set the style.display parameter to none
  e.target.style.display = 'none'

  // use querySelector to get the .layerMiddle element
  //hide the layerMiddle Element
  document.querySelector('.layerMiddle').style.display = 'none'
})
```

```css
div {
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="wysiwyg">text......text...</div>
<div class="layerMiddle">[Layer Middle]</div>
<div class="btn btn-primary verMas">Ver más</div>
```